# "Продукты вроде майонезов, кетчупов" — нужна ли запятая перед "вроде"?

Tags: пунктуация

> Большая часть мясных и рыбных изделий, а также рафинированных продуктов вроде майонезов, кетчупов, соусов содержит консервант бензоат натрия.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ВРОДЕ](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5&all=x)
**I. предлог**, *кого-чего*. Наподобие, в виде кого-либо, чего-либо, как кто-либо, что-либо.
*Начал писать что-то вроде воспоминаний*.

*На стене был нарисован знак вроде перевернутого креста.

Из двух длинных тонких берёз, воткнутых в землю и связанных у верхушек, было сделано нечто вроде ворот.*

Запятая перед «вроде» не нужна (в качестве предлога «вроде» не выделяется запятыми).
Об особенностях пунктуации при употреблении слова «вроде» можно посмотреть [здесь](https://obrazovaka.ru/zapyataya/vrode.html).

Answer (score 1):

*Вроде*, *наподобие*, ***типа***, а также *подобно* — это предлоги, употребляющиеся в речи с родительным падежом слова или оборота.
Никаких оснований для обособления этих падежных форм нет.